# Can PowerMock instantiate an inner class for test cases?

Tags: java, powermock

I'm attempting to test a class with a number of private classes (yes, I know this is generally considered poor practice for testability, but this question is not in regards to design principles).  My class would look something like this:

```
public class EnclosingClass {
  .
  .
  .
  private class InnerClass implements InnerClassType {
     public InnerClass(){ /* do stuff */}
     public int InnerClassMethod();
  }
}
```

- `InnerClassType` is a public interface

I've tried instantiating the classes with powermock by doing:

```
Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class, "InnerClass");
Constructor constructor = Whitebox.getConstructor(clazz, null);
InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) constructor.newInstance(null);
```

and also:

```
Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class, "InnerClass");
InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) Whitebox.invokeConstructor(clazz);
```

However, on both attempts I get a `ConstructorNotFoundException`

Is it possible to instantiate these inner classes?  If so, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to move past your ConstructorNotFoundExeception via the following mods to your first effort:

```
Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class, "InnerClass");
Constructor constructor = Whitebox.getConstructor(clazz, EnclosingClass.class);
InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) constructor.newInstance(new EnclosingClass());
```

Since your inner class is not static, it implicitly expects a "this" reference from the outer class.  Using this method, looks like you have to get explicit with it.

Comment: Given that InnerClass is private, how can you get InnerClassType??

Answer (score -1):

You can mock it like this:

```
InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) Mockito.mock(
    Class.forName(EnclosingClass.class.getName() + "$InnerClass")
);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The op intended to instantiate the inner class to test it. This answer, however, creates a _mock_ of the inner class instead. That mock is - by definition - missing the code that should be made available for testing.