# How to mock a non-static private inner java class with PowerMock and EasyMock?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock, powermock

This [StackOverflowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13242502/2964890) didn't work for me so I recreated the question.

How do I resolve this exception (*powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException*) by only modifying the testClass (*EnclosingClassTest.java*) and not the implementation (*EnclosingClass.java*, *InnerClassType.java*)?

**Requirements:**

- Mock a non-static private inner java class with PowerMock and EasyMock.

**EnclosingClassTest.java :**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ EnclosingClass.class })
public class EnclosingClassTest {

    EnclosingClass cut;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        /* Initialization */

        /* Mock Setup */
        Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class,
                "InnerClass");
        Constructor constructor = Whitebox.getConstructor(clazz, null);
        InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) constructor
                .newInstance(null);

        /* Activate the Mocks */
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        /* Test Method */

        /* Asserts */
        PowerMock.verifyAll();

    }
}
```

**EnclosingClass.java :**

```
public class EnclosingClass {

    private class InnerClass implements InnerClassType {
        public InnerClass() { /* do stuff */
        }

        public int innerClassMethod() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**InnerClassType.java :**

```
public interface InnerClassType {
    public int innerClassMethod();
}
```

EnclosingClassTest.testMethod() throws **Exception:**

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed to lookup constructor with parameter types [ <none> ] in class EnclosingClass$InnerClass.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:258)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.getConstructor(Whitebox.java:158)
    at EnclosingClassTest.testMethod(EnclosingClassTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: EnclosingClass$InnerClass.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException(Class.java:286)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:429)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:250)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to difine the class like this:

```
public class EnclosingClass {

    private static class InnerClass implements InnerClassType {
        public InnerClass() { /* do stuff */
        }

        public int innerClassMethod() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In your definition the InnerClass should belowed to an instance of EnclosingClass. When you are not using reflection, please try out what will going on if you want to instance a InnerClass.

You can get the constructor directly. And passing in an instance of EnclosingClass like this:

```
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        /* Initialization */

        /* Mock Setup */
        Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class,
                "InnerClass");

        Constructor[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
        Constructor c  = constructors[0];
//        c.setAccessible(true);
        InnerClassType innerClass = (InnerClassType) c
                .newInstance(new EnclosingClass());

        /* Activate the Mocks */
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        /* Test Method */

        /* Asserts */
        PowerMock.verifyAll();

    }
```

Comment: If I use your "_public static class EnclosingClass_"suggestion then I get this error : "_Illegal modifier for the class EnclosingClass; only public, abstract & final are permitted_" @Terry Zhao

Comment: But this is now how to mock a static pirvate inner class. @Terry Zhao

Comment: The question asks for no changes to the implementation which is EnclosingClass.java and InnerClassType.java. The implementation is in stone.  @Terry Zhao

Comment: I ran your (@Terry Zhao) updated (modified)  testMethod() and it hung my eclipse. If I put a breakpoint on this line _Class clazz = Whitebox.getInnerClassType(EnclosingClass.class,
                "InnerClass");_ it doesn't even hit this line. I also tried adding _InnerClassType.class_ to the _@PrepareForTest_ anotation parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on your code or env, my eclipse show a green light for this test case after I replace the Junit lib download from powermock with the one defined in Eclipse.