# How to write Junit Test Case for Inner Class that has private access specifier?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I've seen few previous answers for the similar answers. Still I'm unable to understand as I'm new to this. Here my code below

```
package com.kishore.junitTestCases.innerClasses;
public class OuterClass {
   String prefix = "Hello, ";

  private class InnerClasss {
     public String greet(String name) {
        return prefix+name;
     }
  }

  public String displayFromInnerClass() {
     InnerClasss inner = new InnerClasss();
     String greetText = inner.greet("Kishore");
     System.out.println(greetText);
     return greetText;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to write a JunitTestCase without changing anything in the above code? I'm using PowerMockito. Here is my half constructed test case.

```
package com.kishore.junitTestCases.innerClasses;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class OuterClassTest {

   OuterClass outerClass = new OuterClass();

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void displayFromInnerClassTest() throws Exception {
        

   }
}
```

Note: Also could you recommend few best practices? Thank You.

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? We normally test the public interface of code to verify its behaviour. The private method(s) should be tested transitively. --- "*I'm using PowerMockito.*" - A word of caution: PowerMock uses bytecode manipulation. Avoid it if possible.

Comment: When you have something that you both want to test and can't test with the way code is written - it's an indicator that code should be written differently. It's not always possible, and for cases like these there is PowerMock, but it needs to be treated as last resort measure.

Comment: @Turing85 Ok. Usage of PowerMockito, I'll be cautious. I want to test displayFromInnerClass method from the above OuterClass.

Comment: What do you want to test that `assertThat(new OuterClass().displayFromInnerClass()).isEqualTo("Hello, Kishore")` doesn't?

Comment: @Deltharis Yes Deltharis! Exactly. How do I construct it?

Comment: Uh... construct what?

Comment: @Deltharis I mean, Inner Class's greet() that is invoked by displayFromInnerClass() isn't visible. So, How do I test it?

Comment: @Deltharis Even for me to Mock the InnerClass, I'm unable to. That's where I've this blocker. Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: You test it by testing the output of `displayOfInnerClass()`, just as Deltharis demonstrated in their comment. Your use of an inner class is an _implementation detail_. All the unit test is concerned about is if `dispayOfInnerClass()` gives the correct output given certain input.

Comment: @Slaw What if there is a service call in the inline class method that needs to be mocked? And for mocking that, I need to to access the private class right? Don't I?

Comment: Then you should have those services as "injectable" dependencies of the class (e.g. passed via the constructor, or via a method, etc.). During testing you would inject mocks, while in production code you'd inject the real objects.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

It is possible, with great pains, to obtain an instance of an inner class (if it implements a public interface that contains all the methods you need from it) - see [Can PowerMock instantiate an inner class for test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201943/can-powermock-instantiate-an-inner-class-for-test-cases). That way you could test inner class methods.

You can't however, to my knowledge, test outer class while mocking inner class. Inner class lifecycle is intrinsically connected to the outer class instance, and there is no mechanism to replace it.

That you want to highlights a problem in the code you wrote - if invocation of inner class method is not intrinsic part of the operation, if it makes sense to mock the inner class in order to test the outer class - than it should not be a private inner class, it should be an injected dependency, precicely because you can then mock and test them in isolation.